# Table onclick rows jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've a table whose content is getting generated via an AJAX success response.

**HTML code**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table_content"></table>
```

**AJAX code**

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type : "POST",
        url: "/configuration/",
        data : { 'selected_item' : selected_item_id },

        success : function(result){
                 var table_heading = "<tr>"
                 var table_content = ""
                 for (var heads in result[1]){
                     table_heading +="<th style='background-color:#f1f1f1;'>" + result[1][heads] + "</th>"
                 }

                 for (var region in result[0]){
                      table_content += "<tr>"
                      for (var details in result[0][region]){
                          table_content += "<td>" + result[0][region][details] + "</td>"
                      }
                 }

                 table_content = table_heading + table_content

                 $("#table_content").html(table_content)
       },
});
```

I want to apply an onclick function to it. Like this:-

**Onclick function code**

```
$(function(){
    $('#table_content tr').click(function () {
        $('.test').slideUp(0)
        $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));
    });
});
```

The issue that I'm facing is that I'm not able to click the row, if I generate the content via AJAX response. If I create a table inside the HTML itself, it'll work, but not when the table is created via AJAX response.

What's the problem? Please sugggest.

**EDITED**

What I'm trying to achieve is that a div should be slide down just below the row upon clicking the row. I does works for the first time when the data gets generated via AJAX. but it does not works when I'm generating data after the first time, though the event is triggered but `$('.test').slideUp(0) $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));` does not works after the first time. Nor any error is popped . See http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:
See working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/c5FgG/1/

Your problem was that you attached the test div element to a table row, which dissapeared after repopulating the table. Instead, clone the test div on each click when you are changing the table content, and use the clone instead the original.

Old answer:
Add the onclick function code inside the ajax success function. It works out for me this way:

```
...
$("#table_content").html(table_content);

$('#table_content tr').click(function () {
  alert("Clicked");
  //your code
});
...
```

And don't forget to close the table rows with:

```
table_content += "</tr>";
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that a div should be slide down just below the row upon clicking the row. I does works for the first time when the data gets generated via AJAX. but it does not works when I'm generating data after the first time, though the event is triggered but `$('.test').slideUp(0) $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));` does not works after the first time. Nor any error is popped . See http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/5/

Comment: In that case your I know exactly what your problem is. You are adding the div with class="test" to another location of the dom (inside each tr), then, when you are getting data for second time, there will be no more div to append. To solve it, clone your test div, and append it to each row. And leave alone the original one.

Comment: Thanks for it. But what if I have different divs for each different item list ?

Comment: You mean the data for the div is coming from the json result? I don't see the problem even if you need to slide down different content.

Comment: I mean its like this. For Item 1 - `<div id = '1'>abc</div>`. For Item 2 - `<div id = '2'>def</div>`. For Item 3 - `<div id = '3'>aghi</div>` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are using `click` to bind the event only binds the event to elements that are present in `DOM` at time the binding code is executed. You need event delegation for binding event with dynamically generated html elements using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(function(){
    $('#table_content').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $('.test').slideUp(0)
        $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));
    });
});
```

**Delegated events**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Is click event is triggered?

Comment: No. It triggers for the first time, when the table is already there. But when the table gets generated via ajax response, it does not works.

Comment: No. wait its working, but what I'm trying to achieve is not getting generated. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: Click event should be triggered, please review your code to ensure everthing is fine and you do not have errors

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that a div should be slide down just below the row upon clicking the row. I does works for the first time when the data gets generated via AJAX. but it does not works when I'm generating data after the first time, though the event is triggered but `$('.test').slideUp(0)
        $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));` does not works after the first time. Nor any error is popped.

Comment: Can you make a demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('#table_content').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $('.test').slideUp(0)
        $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));
    });
});
```

The `on()` handler should work on newly created elements too.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that a div should be slide down just below the row upon clicking the row. I does works for the first time when the data gets generated via AJAX. but it does not works when I'm generating data after the first time, though the event is triggered but `$('.test').slideUp(0) $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));` does not works after the first time. Nor any error is popped . See http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for **dynamically added elements** like,

```
$('#table_content').on('click',' tr', function () {
    $('.test').slideUp(0)
    $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));
});
```

**Updated** your `div` will move to `tr` which you `clicked`, so when you `click` on `list` it will `generate new content` in `table` so your `div.test` will be removed from `HTML`, thats why you are not getting the `desc div` again.

To solve this problem you have to add `div.desc` again in `clicking of list` like,

```
if(!$('body > div.test').length){
   $("body").append('<div class="test">You slide down a row with content xyz</div>');
}
```

**Full code**

```
 $('#list').on('click', 'li', function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var table_content = "";
    // IF id=1,2,3,4,5 Code        

    $("#table_content").html(table_content);

    // add below code foe div.desc
    if (!$('body > div.test').length) {
        $("body").append('<div class="test">You slide down a row with content xyz</div>');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mS3h4/)

**Alternatively,** you can use [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone) like,

```
$(function () {
    $('#table_content').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $clone=$('.test:not(.new-test)').clone();// clone the first test class element
        $('.new-test').remove();// remove the cloned elements
        $clone.addClass('new-test').appendTo('body');// add the clone to body
        $clone.slideUp(0);// playing with clone now
        $(this).append($clone.slideDown('slow'));
    });
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mS3h4/1/)

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that a div should be slide down just below the row upon clicking the row. I does works for the first time when the data gets generated via AJAX. but it does not works when I'm generating data after the first time, though the event is triggered but `$('.test').slideUp(0) $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));` does not works after the first time. Nor any error is popped . See http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/5/

Comment: No its not. Please see the description below that what issue I'm exactly facing.

Comment: I want that a div should slide down just below the row which is clicked. It does works but only for the 1st time when I generate the data via Ajax. Upon generating the table after the 1st time, the div does not slides down. For eg:- When I click an `li` item a table will appear. Upon clicking on any of the rows, a div will appear saying `You slide down a row with content xyz`. but when I click an item again from the list, and then the row from the corresponding table, the div doesn't shows up.

Comment: Its working, but I didnt understood what `if (!$('body > div.test').length) {
        $("body").append('<div class="test">You slide down a row with content xyz</div>');
    }` does?

Comment: When you click on any `table-row` then your `div.desc` moves in that row, it will work fine, but when your click again on `list-li` then the `div.desc` in your `table-tr` will be `removed` from `table` `body` as `new contents` takes place in `table. So, I checked the length of `div.desc` if it is zero then I append it again in `body`.

Comment: Logical enough. But This was just a demo. In reality , the div content is very large, so I cannot append like `$("body").append('<div class="test">You slide down a row with content xyz</div>');`, thereby re-writting the whole content of the div again. Is there something like I just pass an id/class and the content of the div in appended. something like `$("body").append(ID/CLASS OF THE DIV)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43421/discussion-between-rohan-kumar-and-user1162512)

Comment: Sir, But what if I have different divs for each different item list ?I mean its like this. For Item 1 - `<div id = '1'>abc</div>`. For Item 2 - `<div id = '2'>def</div>`. For Item 3 - `<div id = '3'>aghi</div>` and so on. I cannot clone for each and every div. Right?

Comment: You can use `div-id` in place of `$('.test').clone()` like `$('div#1').clone()` for each `active-li`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#table_content').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $('.test').slideUp(0)
        $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));
    });
});
```

Here Is a list of fiddles :

[fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/2q56r/)

[fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/y8fBy/)

[fiddle3](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/Bw97W/)

[fiddle4](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/SUwLM/)

You can use it as per your requirement.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that a div should be slide down just below the row upon clicking the row. I does works for the first time when the data gets generated via AJAX. but it does not works when I'm generating data after the first time, though the event is triggered but `$('.test').slideUp(0) $(this).append(($('.test')).slideDown('slow'));` does not works after the first time. Nor any error is popped . See http://jsfiddle.net/fVz6D/5/

Comment: Will You tell me, what actually you want to do ?

Comment: I want that a div should slide down just below the row which is clicked. It does works but only for the 1st time when I generate the data via Ajax. Upon generating the table after the 1st time, the div does not slides down. For eg:- When I click an `li` item a table will appear. Upon clicking on any of the rows, a div will appear saying `You slide down a row with content xyz`. but when I click an item again from the list, and then the row from the corresponding table, the div doesn't shows up.

Comment: See Update I have added fiddles, you can use as you want.